# Signal and voltage

Tags: motherboard

What is the difference between voltage and signal?
In power sequence of motherboards, there are signals and supplies. Supplies are voltages but how is a signal generated?? Is signal related to both Voltage and current?

Answer (score 7):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal):

> A signal as referred to in communication systems, signal processing, and electrical engineering is a function that "conveys information about the behavior or attributes of some phenomenon".

A signal is used to communicate with another part of the circuit by changing some attribute, whether it be a changing voltage, changing current, changing resistance, etc. Voltage is a physical phenomenon and refers to the potential difference between two points. A signal is usually generated and transmitted using voltage.

Comment: Good, concise answer!

Comment: A signal is a physical phenomenon which carries some kind of information. It must not necessarily be electrical. It can also be mechanical, acustical, optical,...

Comment: @LvW Fair point!

Answer (score 2):

In short, a *signal* is intended to transfer *information*.  Voltage is one physical property that can be varied in order encode information.

Answer (score 0):

As a concrete example to go with DerStrom8's [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/384583/40447), if I have a wire that has some changing voltage on it, that's all I can say that I have: voltages.  However, if I happen to know that the voltages on that wire are encoding information as defined in [RS-232](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232) (The serial port protocol) and [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) (character encoding), I can *interpret* those voltages as a signal, and discover that you were intending to convey the signal "Hello world" across that wire by using voltages.  You could have also used smoke signals, which would change the medium from voltages to puffs of smoke, but the signal would remain the same.

Or, perhaps more succinct: The difference between a bunch of flashing colored lights and a traffic signal is that you, as a driver, know that the traffic signal is intended to communicate information to you, and you know how to interpret those flashing lights (Green means "go," red means "stop")